# Unable to move xlib window until app focus is changed

Tags: xlib

I create a single xlib window with the relevant code below. When I try to move the window, the cursor briefly changes to the grab cursor and I am unable to drag the window. However, if I change focus to another app, then return to my app, I am able to drag the window. I am new to xlib, and don't understand why I cannot drag the window after creation?

```
ms_display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

int screen = DefaultScreen(ms_display);
Window rootWindow = RootWindow(ms_display,screen);

XSetWindowAttributes windowAttrib;

windowAttrib.background_pixel = 0;
windowAttrib.border_pixel = 0;
windowAttrib.colormap = XCreateColormap(ms_display,rootWindow,m_visual,AllocNone);
windowAttrib.event_mask = StructureNotifyMask | KeyPressMask | KeyReleaseMask | ButtonPressMask | PointerMotionMask | FocusChangeMask | EnterWindowMask | LeaveWindowMask;
int width = m_displayInfo.m_windowWidth;
int height = m_displayInfo.m_windowHeight;
unsigned long mask = CWBackPixel | CWBorderPixel | CWColormap | CWEventMask;

ms_window = XCreateWindow(ms_display,rootWindow,0,0,width,height, 0, pVisInfo->depth,
                    InputOutput,pVisInfo->visual,mask,&windowAttrib);

XMapWindow(ms_display, ms_window);

XFlush(ms_display);

XSizeHints sizeHints;
sizeHints.x = (WidthOfScreen(ScreenOfDisplay(ms_display, screen)) - width) / 2;
sizeHints.y = (HeightOfScreen(ScreenOfDisplay(ms_display, screen)) - height) / 2;
sizeHints.width = width;
sizeHints.height = height;
sizeHints.flags = USPosition | USSize;
XSetWMSizeHints(ms_display,ms_window,&sizeHints,XInternAtom(ms_display,"WM_SIZE_HINTS",False));
XMoveResizeWindow(ms_display,ms_window,sizeHints.x,sizeHints.y,width,height);
```

Comment: Show a complete runnable program.

Answer (score 0):

I did run into a somewhat similar situation, where a newly created window would not get focus, receive mouse clicks or keyboard input until I called XSetWMHints(), even with a completely empty structure, e.g. the following was enough to get it working:

```
XWMHints xwmh;
xwmh.flags = 0;
XSetWMHints (m_display, m_window, &xwmh);
```

Weird, but it solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that doesn't work for me, no matter where I place it.